# apache: log separate time to generate and serve php requests

Tags: php, apache, logging, profiling

By Googling, I can see it's possible for Apache to log the time it took to serve a document.

I am looking for two distinct numbers: the time it took *Apache* to *serve* the document, and the time it took *PHP* to *execute*. (Ideally also separate numbers for I/O and processing, but I expect that will require a heavyweight PHP profiler rather than a lightweight Apache change.)

I am new to Apache configuration. How can I get these two numbers, with the host/path?query string, for each request?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) is a good example of how to get the script execution time. I'm not sure how to get the info from Apache.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php